# How i can list selected value as selected and other values as listin php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I want to display selected value as selected and others list in drop down.how it is possible inforeach loop

```
<?php $physicaldata = explode(",",$physical); 
?>

<select name="PEPhysical[]" multiple onchange="GetrestPhysical(this.value);">
<?php   foreach ($physicaldata as $physical)

{?>   
<option <?php if($physical   == 'Normal'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Normal" >Normal Person</option>
<option<?php if($physical   == 'Deaf/Dumb'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Deaf/Dumb">Deaf/Dumb</option>
<option<?php if($physical   == 'Blind'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Blind">Blind</option>
<option<?php if($physical   == 'Physically Challenged'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Physically Challenged">Physically Challenged</option>
<option <?php if($physical   == 'Mentally Challenged'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>value="Mentally Challenged">Mentally Challenged</option>
<option <?php if($physical   == 'With other Disability'){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?> value="With other Disability">With other Disability</option>
<?php  } ?>
```

but now listing morethan onetime(look uploaded image)[image: this is now i am getting output]

how i can change listing value display ones.?

Answer (score 0):

Either do the foreach over possible values, and check whether the value is in selected values (only one option tag in your code then since you'r printing it in a loop):

```
<?php   foreach ($possibleValues as $possibleValue)

{?>   
<option <?php
    if($selectedValues[$possibleValue->id]){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } 
?> value="<?php
    echo $possibleValue->id
?>" ><?php
    echo $possibleValue->description
?></option>
<?php  } ?>
```

Or print them as you do, but then don't use a for loop to print them - use a loop or better an associative array to check whether each of them is selected.

Comment: Did you actually read it and implement it, or did you just copy-paste it? What did you initialize `$possibleValues` and `$selectedValues` to?